# Cloning / Copying value of multi-value field

Tags: entities

I do not wanna create another wheel but could not find a solution yet.

I have multi-value field (which I implemented myself) and I would like to have possibility to add 'new item' with already predefined values.

What would you recommend to do?

I googled and did not find anything suitable for me and considering to create my own module for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Entity References and not a complex compound field like your using now.

By using references you can use either the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) or the [References Dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog) modules to provide a more streamlined UI for adding new events from new popup windows. I was hoping you could reference exisitng events through a search using these modules (you can) but it won't clone the reference directly.

BUT, you could use the [Replicate](https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate) module, to replicated the entity reference you've selected to then edit it -- using custom code.

[An example way to replicate a referenced entity can be seen in this replicate issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2019687), as shown below:

```
/**
 * Replicate entities that are the target of entityreference fields 
 *
 * Implements hook_replicate_field_FIELD_TYPE
 *
 * For entites that have one or more entity reference fields we need to replicate the
 * referenced entities as well so the cloned parents don't all point to the same children.
 * We also need to update the entityreference fields to point to them.
 * 
 * @param object $replica
 *   Reference to the fully loaded entity object being saved (the clone) that
 *   can be altered as needed.
 * @param string $entity_type
 *   Type of the entity containing the field.
 * @param string $field_name
 *   Name of the field that is going to be processed.
 *
 * @see replicate_clone_entity()
 */

function MY_MODULE_replicate_field_entityreference(&$replica, $entity_type, $field_name) {

  // Only replicate entity reference field you are interested in
  if ($field_name == 'field_MY_ENTITYREFERENCE_FIELD') {

    // Wrap the replicated entity.
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $replica);

    // Loop over the field values
    foreach ($wrapper->$field_name as $delta => $referenced_field_item_wrapper) {
      $referenced_entity = $referenced_field_item_wrapper->value();

      // Replicate the referenced entity and get the new id
      $replicated_referenced_entity_id = replicate_entity('node', $referenced_entity);

      // Give the replica reference field the new target id
      $replica->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta]['target_id'] = $replicated_referenced_entity_id;
    }
  }
}
```

So I'm saying Replicate and 1 of the many "dialog" modules could help make what you want to create more pretty. You could probably use the Replicate API and a custom button in your own form too -- if you want to do even more learning ... :)